# href syntax in allowing javascript

Tags: javascript, syntax, href

I was wondering whether injecting javascript into an href tag with some text inside is possible or not.
Now i know you can do this:

```
<a href="javascript:alert(1)">
```

Now if the href value already has some text like:

```
<a href="Hello welcome to xxxx site">
```

Within the quotes how will it be possible to inject some javascript?
Something like this:

```
<a href="Hello welcome to xxxx site javascript:alert(2)">
```

I know i could start another part like `onmouseover="alert(1)"` but i'm wondering whether it's possible to do so within the href tags in that circumstance.

Comment: Does something like this fit your needs?  This is the best way because it keeps javascript logic separated from markup: [http://api.jquery.com/bind/](http://api.jquery.com/bind/)

Comment: @user1161625 It is the best.

Comment: Sorry, first time I posted a link with the mini-markup like that... took me a couple tries ;)

Comment: @gibberish What he posted is irrelevant to what i asked.

Comment: Ah. Your comment reply seemed to say that his answer was best for you. Apologies for the misunderstanding.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why would you have non-URL text inside an href tag (or is that just an example)? Perhaps if you give us more info about what you are trying to do we can improve our responses?

Comment: @gibberish My answer was directed to the question "Does something like this fit your needs?" Anyway i'm not looking for workarounds, my question was put as it is, if it were possible to achieve what i asked, the answer was no.

Comment: Alright, thanks Bob. Please answer your own question and choose it as the correct answer when the system allows you to do so.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
<a href="javascript:alert('Hello welcome to xxxx site')">
```

Using `javascript:` is actually bad form in an HREF. You should be using a null anchor "`#`" and using `onclick` instead.

A better way is:

```
<a href="#" data-text="Hello welcome to xxxx site">...</a>
```

...Then using JavaScript to hook up the event handler and access the HTML5 data element.

Comment: No, i'm asking if in the circumstance i provided if it's possible to add javascript while having the text excluded from the javascript part.

Comment: No, because when the user clicks on that the browser will think the text is a URL and will fail.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for (improved example)?

```
<body>

    The a tag is below:<br />
    <a href="javascript:alert('Hello');window.location.href='http://google.com';alert('there');">Click here</a>

</body>
```

Comment: I was referring to having some text before the javascript: part within the href tags and still be able to execute javascript.

Comment: You would need to create a js command for that first part, before appending the js. In other words, convert your first bit to a js command and chain them.